# Converting Pandas Object data type to String

Tags: python, pandas, string, object

I can't get individual columns or my entire dataframe to convert to a string. I'm reading in data from s3 into a pandas, like such:

```
bucket = 'my_bucket'
file_name = 'my_path/my_file.csv'
s3 = boto3.client('s3') 
s3_obj = s3.get_object(Bucket = bucket, Key = file_name)
df = pd.read_csv(s3_obj['Body'])
df = df.astype(str)
df['col1']= df['col1'].astype(str)
print(df.dtypes)
```

I'm trying both: converting the entire dataframe or a column to a string. When I run the print statement, it shows all columns and the df as an 'object'.

How do I convert this to a string?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding dtype=str as an argument to read_csv function:

```
df = pd.read_csv(s3_obj['Body'], dtype=str)
```

If you want certain columns to be interpreted as column you can specify that in dtype as:

```
mydtypes = {'col1': 'str', 'col2': 'str', 'col3': 'str', 'col4': 'float'}
df = pd.read_csv(s3_obj['Body'], dtype=mydtypes)
```

Comment: I feel like this is close, but still not working. I tried both options you listed, and neither work.

Answer (score 0):

String dtype is new from pandas 1.0.0.

You can use `series.astype("string")` instead of `series.astype(str)`

Documentation is here https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/text.html.